# Language Input Selection Dialog shortcut

Tags: macos, keyboard, catalina

I am using Catalina 10.15.3, and I am struggling to find the small dialog that is shown when switching between languages. That dialog showed all the input languages that I selected. Sometimes, I use apps in full screen and when I change the input language with shortcut I will need to reach the topbar with mouse so that I can see what language is being selected.

I am looking for that input language change dialog.

P.S. I am not sure about the word 'dialog'. It is a just a small window just pops in the middle of the screen and disappears in a couple of seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Ask Different.

You could enable/set keyboard shortcuts for changing input sources. Go to `System Preferences` > `Keyboard` > `Shortcuts` settings, and in the left pane select `Input sources`. Then just enable the two command shortcuts for changing input sources. I've attached an image of what the settings looks like below. You can enable and/or change the shortcut to your liking.

[image]

When I use the shortcut, the input sources dialog box shows as long as you hold down the shortcut keys (see image below).

[image]

I'm doing all of this on macOS Mojave, but I think this works in Catalina too. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, enabling `...previous input source` did the trick. Thank you so much for making my life so much easies :). Have a good day kind man